# Distributed Transaction Coordinator

Tags: msdtc

I am trying make a database transaction(inserting records) across multiple system. So, I decided to use System.Transaction Namespace in .net. I configured MSDTC on both system(But i dont know whether i configured correctly). My transaction has two insert query one will execute at local system. another, will execute at some other system in a local network.
First insert query work successfully but second one raise a error like :
Message = "The transaction has already been implicitly or explicitly committed or aborted."

---

Here is my Code

```
    using (TransactionScope txSc = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //vrm = new VolatileRM();
        //vrm.SetMemberValue(3);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr1))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into empdetail Values ('YYY')";
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into stu Values ('23','senthil')";
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }                    
            txSc.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            txSc.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit to include your code that encloses the whole transaction.

Comment: @Partha: just wondering if you were going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 3):

First check that the DTC is actually running (on local and remote system), and then try setting both DTC's authentication to 'anonymous' to see if it's a permissions problem.

Also, check the firewall settings on remote and local machine.

Check out this FAQ: [Distributed Transaction Coordinator(MSDTC) and Transaction FAQ](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/173c937d-3fdc-43ab-8127-6083cef29a0e/)

[Configuring MS DTC Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753866.aspx)

- [Enable Network Access Securely for MS DTC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753620.aspx)
- [Enable Firewall Exceptions for MS DTC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725913.aspx)

Related to this SO question: [HRESULT: 0x8004D00E using TransactionScope - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784047/hresult-0x8004d00e-using-transactionscope-c/784070#784070)

Comment: Thanks Mitch Wheat, After set firewall to off. It is works. Thanks Lot

Comment: @Sarathis1904 If Mitch's answer fixed it then do mark it as the answer and upvote.

Comment: @Sarathis1904: setting firewall to off has verified it, but please don't leave it turned off! See the link above: Enable Firewall Exceptions for MS DTC