# MSDTC issues - transaction times out with Event ID 4359

Tags: msdtc

I have a baffling issue with MSDTC

We have 4 machines in our development project but only 1 cannot negotiate a MSDTC transaction.

We are using WCF service, with multiple Linq-2-SQL DataContexts, so the transaction is being escalated to the DTC.  1 machine ( Windows 7 SP 1 ) out of 4 fails when invoking a second datacontext call.

The DB server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2008 R2

This is the event log

Source: MSDTC Client
Event ID: **4359**
Task Category: MSDTC Proxy
General: “MS DTC is unable to communicate with MS DTC on a remote system. MS DTC on the primary system established an RPC binding with MS DTC on the secondary system. However, the secondary system did not create the reverse RPC binding to the primary MS DTC system before the timeout period expired. Please ensure that there is network connectivity between the two systems.  Error Specifics:”

MSDTC is setup the same on all 4 machine,
Network DTC Access - Enabled
Client and Administration - Both Allow Remote Clients and Allow Remote Administration checked
Transaction Manager Communication - Allow outbound and Allow inbound checked, Mutual Authentication Required
Enable XA Transaction unchecked
Enable SNA LU 6.2 Transactions checked

All machines ( includeing the DB server ) has the DTC logon account set to NT Authority\NetworkService

I have checked that the failing machine can resolve the DB server by NETBIOS name, and that **ping -a {IP}** resolves the IP address back to the netbios name, and vise versa.

When the transaction is escalated to the DTC, I see an entry in the transaction list, on both client and DB server, in the form of  user_transaction { SOME GUID }, which times out after about 1 minute

The DB is not logging anything on it's event logs

There is no difference if all firewalls are disabled.

Does anyone have any idea what to look at next ?

Cheers...

Robert

=== Update ===
MSDTC was incorrectly configured on the machine... the dev box was cloned from an image and replicated some internal GUIDs.  Reinstalling MSDTC fixed the issue

```
msdtc -uninstall
msdtc -install
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796416/distributed-transaction-coordinator

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774304(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Can the DB server resolve the failing machine name?  That's a common problem I've had in the past.  Try [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e325025-4dcd-4658-a549-1d549ac17644) to help diagnose.

Comment: @Robert Thanks - msdtc reinstall did the trick - seems a common problem with cloned / ghosted machines. More on it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891801). Note that a reboot is needed as well.